# hecr parse json c# y dividirlo en textbox

Tags: c#, jsonobject

buen dia a todos !!

tengo poco tiempo trabajando con objetos Json, recibo una respuesta desde un servicio web con la siguiente estructura json,

```
{
"ErrorMsg":"",
"Data":
        {
            "WorkOrder":"5300000221",
            "ERPPartNo":"IN00252888",
            "Program":"T",
            "ERPPartName":"",
            "DateCode":"20240206",
            "PartGroup":"9000",
            "Quantity":56.0,
            "BoxLableCode":"F20240206000001",
            "Unit":"PC"
        },  
"Success":true
```

}

lo que quiero hacer es separar la lista en textbox en un windows forms, alguien me podria compartir algun ejemplo?

Saludos !!

Comment: `separar la lista en textbox` cual lista ??? cual textbox?

Comment: Podrías crear una clase tipo Data y desearializar la respuesta del servicio web con Newtonsoft.Json, así con la clase ya podrías trabajar fácilmente seteando en los textbox correspondientes